# "Could not open connection" when using org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute?

Tags: java

I'm trying to open a connection:

```
HttpPost hp = new HttpPost();
HttpParams rp = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpClientConnection hc = new DefaultHttpClientConnection();
HttpContext hctx = new BasicHttpContext();

hp.setURI(new URI(baseUrl + "/login.jsp"));
rp.setParameter("os_username", username);
rp.setParameter("os_password", password);
rp.setParameter("os_destination", "/secure");
hp.setParams(rp);

HttpResponse response = httpexecutor.execute(hp, hc, hctx);
```

But, I'm getting this stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection is not open
    at org.apache.http.impl.SocketHttpClientConnection.assertOpen(SocketHttpClientConnection.java:76)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.sendRequestHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:239)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest(HttpRequestExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124)
```

what could be causing a "Connection is not open"? I don't see any specific methods that I can use to force open the connection.

Comment: most likely your URL is wrong

Comment: is there a reason for using `HttpRequestExecutor` rather than something like `HttpGet` ?

Answer (score 0):

As I remember this needs to be surrounded by:

```
try{
...code...
} catch (Exception e) {
out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage()); //or System.out.println
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have some code that threw errors like that before I surrounded it with the try/catch, after it worked like a dream. Java can be 'temperamental'